# Download base64 encoded image IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, base64

I want to download image without making request to the server. Can't get it work in IE:

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA
AANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0l
EQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6
P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" download="downloadedimage"> download</a>
```

Is there any solution?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pPMN2/

Answer (score 1):

Similar to other questions - [Data URI doesn't work with IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233034/data-uri-doesnt-work-with-ie)

Really the solution is to go server side

Here's some more information that may help

http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute