# Data URI doesn't work with IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, stream

Im trying to dynamically create a CSV file using javascript that the user can download. This only has to work in IE.

The html the javascript generates looks something like this

```
 <a href="data:application/octet-stream,field1%2Cfield2%0Afoo%2Cbar%0Agoo%2Cgai%0A">CSV</a>
```

Which seams to work fine in chrome but IE10 just breaks.

Is there a better way to dynamically create a file using JavaScript and then give the user a link to download it? I cant use PHP as the entire system needs to run on the client-side due to restrictions placed by the user. The system all needs to work on a touch screen (with no right click option) so the link needs to give the user the ability to download, not open the file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Internet Explorer 10 doesn't support the `data` protocol on the `a` element. Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc848897), the only supported elements/attributes are the following:

- object (images only)
- img
- input type=image
- link
- CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background, backgroundImage, and so on.

You should know that what you're attempting to do smells like a phishing attempt; for this reason you shouldn't expect browsers to support this pattern. You can read more about data-uri phishing in the paper [Phishing by data URI](http://klevjers.com/papers/phishing.pdf).

Comment: Hi Thanks for this. What I'm working on is an app for the national healthcare service (UK), its a survey system which they have dictated must run as a web page, on the client side only but allow them to download the survey data. 

I resolved my problem by using a SWF based downloader, but thanks for your responce.

Comment: @CJH Why don't you just generate a link? It works in IE too and does not require flash... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767200/is-there-a-polyfill-for-link-download-with-data-uri/42769345#42769345

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I download the data uri in this way with Chrome:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = dataItem.Filename;
link.href = data;
link.click();
```

But it does not work in Internet Explorer. I have found a library that works in Internet Explorer,  https://github.com/rndme/download

The only issue for me is the dowload of files with longer MIME type like odt, docx, etc. For all the other kind of files it look great!